# Java: is there a way to convert text into a class?

Tags: java, reflection

I have the input: `"ListClients param1 param2"`
which splits by `" "` to `"ListClients", "param1", "param2";`

and I want to call a static method from ListClients.

So it would do `ListClients.someMethodThatTakesPraams(param1, param2);`

is there a way to do that in java?

Comment: 'magic'....interesting tag choice. :D

Comment: I removed the magic tag since it doesn't apply

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes indeed!  You can use `Class.getDeclaredMethod` to look up a `Method` object given a name and the types of the parameters.  For example, to find your `someMethodThatTakesParams` method, you could write

```
Method m = ListClients.class.getDeclaredMethod("someMethodThatTakesParams", ArgType1.class, ArgType2.class);
```

Here, `ArgType1` and `ArgType2` are the types of the arguments.

Once you have the method, you can invoke it as follows:

```
m.invoke(null, arg1, arg2);
```

Where `arg1` and `arg2` are the parameters you want to pass.  Note that the first argument to `invoke` is `null` because the method is static.

This approach omits all sorts of weirdness with exceptions you have to catch and security permissions you might have to acquire, but fortunately those aren't that hard to pick up.

Comment: +1 For the correct answer. Unfortunately reflection is not this straightforward and some considerations should be taken to avoid invoking just any available method. You could alternatively code statically  what methods could/should be invoked. It requires more work, but it is safer.

Comment: @OscarRyz- That is an excellent point.  In general reflection is massively overkill.  Since I don't know any more about what the OP is trying to do, I still stand by this answer, though I completely agree with you that static dispatching would be a much, much better idea.

Comment: In that case you could upvote my answer :) :) :) ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730009/java-is-there-a-way-to-convert-text-into-a-class/4730192#4730192

Comment: @OscarRyz- Currently out of votes.  I'll try to remember to upvote once I get them back. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can use reflection. Below is an e.g. of creating a new instance

```
Class<Object> fc = Class.forName("ListClients");
   Object myObj = fc.newInstance();
```

Here are some examples of [invoking methods](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.lang.reflect/calling-a-method-dynamically-using-refle.html)

Comment: I think this is a cleaner answer if reflection has to be used.

Answer (score 2):

The simple hard coded way would be to create an if/else chain and invoke the right method:

```
String input = "ListClients param1 param2";
String [] args = input.split(" ");
switch( args.length ) { 
    case 0: 
       return ListClients.someMethod();
    case 1: 
       return ListClients.someMethod( args[0] );
    case 2: 
        return LIstClients.someMethod( args[1] );
    default: 
         return // something default         
}
```

While this may seem a bit antiquate, it is very safe, because you program exactly how your code should be invoked.

The other solution would involve using reflection as others mention:

```
String input = "ListClients param1 param2";
String [] args = input.split(" ");
Class[] types = new Classs[ args.length ];
Object[] values = new Object[ args.lenght ];
for( int i = 0 ; i < types.lenght ; i++ ) { 
   types[i] = String.class;
   values [i] = args[i];
 }   

ListClients.class
   .getDeclaredMethod("someMethod", types )
   .invoke( null, values );
```

All that surrounded by a number of reflection checked exceptions.

You should consider how dynamic you need your application to be, and / if you would do something to prevent a wild call like this:  *"System.exit(0)"*  be invoked or any other sort of [code injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection).

Answer (score -1):

[Reflection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html) will be your friend.

Comment: +1 Because I don't think this post merited a downvote. Though it is certainly not the most helpful thing to simply post a tutorial link and no explanation.

Comment: @Tim Bender I accept that, but there are things that you can safely use without really knowing much about them and there are things you can nuke your code with if you don't understand them. Reflection definitely falls into the second category. Moreover, I thought OP would find the name of the whole concept useful.)